# How to play particles out of child

Tags: c#, parent-child, particles, unity-game-engine

Structure is *Cube+Bridge>Cube>CubeTrigger* where I want to attach script OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) and

I want to turn on 4 particles that are 
*Cube+Bridge>Cube>ParticleGroup>Fire1, Fire2, Fire3, Fire4*.

How to get to them?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are asking but if you want to play your particles based on OnTriggerEnter you could do it a few different ways.

I would either enable the particle system when OnTriggerEnter is called or instantiate the system at the location of the child.

You will probably want to make a reference in the script for the Particle system and enable or instantiate it that way.

Comment: I wanna know what is the code to play particle system that is attached to other object. I'm new to programming so I lack some basics.

Comment: Declare the variable like you would with any string or int like so
<code>ParticleSystem    nameOfParticles;
            
OnTriggerEnter(){ nameOfParticles.enabled; } </code>

Comment: If you need more help post the code you have now and I'll be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CubeTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public ParticleSystem Flame1;
    public ParticleSystem Flame2;
    public ParticleSystem Flame3;
    public ParticleSystem Flame4;

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {

        Flame1.Play ();
        Flame2.Play ();
        Flame3.Play ();
        Flame4.Play ();
    }
}
```

That was quite easy task. I forgot that I can just drag and drop particle I wanna use :) thx